# How many different ways are there to draw a seven followed by an eight?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

Consider a basic deck of cards with 32 cards (stripped deck). We draw 7 cards out of this set and do not replace them. How many different ways are there to draw a seven followed by an eight?

My logic is the following:

First, we should consider how many ways to draw a seven from the deck. It makes 4 ways.The same logic applies to the number of possible ways to draw an eight. It also makes 4 ways. Then, we should consider the number of different ways to draw the other 5 cards without taking their order into the account for the time being: $\binom{30}{5}$. Since a seven and an eight are supposed to follow one another, we will consider them as a single item that cannot be split. To conclude, we will count the number of ways to arrange 5 cards and one merged item (a seven followed by an eight): $6!$

The number of ways is equal to $4*4*\binom{30}{5}*6!$...

However, what disturbs me in this line of reasoning is that the combination of a seven followed by an eight might be counted twice when it is a part of a merged item and when it is a part of the group of five other cards.

Could you please give me a hint on how to solve this problem in the correct way?

Comment: In your method, how do you handle draws such as $7\spadesuit\,8\spadesuit \, 7\clubsuit\,8\clubsuit\,7\diamondsuit\,8\diamondsuit\,A\spadesuit$? If, as it appears, you have counted that three times, then you have to subtract out some cases.

Comment: Yes, that's the point of my question. I do not understand in which elegant way to subtract all these repeated pairs from the total count

Comment: Elegant is probably not going to happen.  But you can easily use your method to count those hands that contain at least  $\textit {two}$ instances of $78$.  Then count those that contain three.

Comment: To simplify: let A be the number of hands where the pair 78 appears once, B - twice, C - three times. Then the number of all different hands where a seven is followed by an eight is equal $A-(B-C)$. Do I understand correctly that this operation eliminates all cases of double count?

Comment: Yes, that looks right to me.  Provided you mean "at least once", and "at least twice"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $i=1,2,3,4,5,6$ let $D_i$ denote the set of draws where the $i$-th card is a seven and the $i+1$-th card is an eight.

Then to be found is $\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^6 D_i\right|$ and we can apply the principle of inclusion/exclusion.

To be well equipped we first make the following observations:

- $6|D_1|=6\times(4\times4\times30\times29\times28\times27\times26)=1641669120$
- $10|D_1\cap D_3|=10\times(4\times4\times3\times3\times28\times27\times26)=28304640$
- $4|D_1\cap D_3\cap D_5|=4\times(4\times4\times3\times3\times2\times2\times26)=59904$

Observe that e.g. factor $10$ in second bullet equals the number combinations $D_i\cap D_j$ we will engage with $1\leq i<j\leq6$ and $D_i\cap D_j\neq\varnothing$.

Then:$$\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^6 D_i\right|=6|D_1|-10|D_1\cap D_3|+4|D_1\cap D_3\cap D_5|=1613424384$$

Comment: I agree with this logic. However, there is a miscalculation in $6|D_1|$. It should normally equal to $1 641 669 120$ which makes $1 627 526 784$ number of cases in total. I used another method described in the comments above and arrived exactly to the same result.

Comment: I repaired $6|D_1|$ and adaptad but unfortunately the totals still dismatch...